# HTML+CSS+JS item.classList.toggle() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, card

I am writing a program aiming to flip the card while it is clicked. The javascript code looks like this:

```
/* card flipping onclick */
import "./Stylesheets/FlipCardStyle.css"

var cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');

[...cards].forEach((card)=>{
    card.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
        card.classList.toggle('flipped');
    });
});
```

And the CSS code works like this:

```
@import "GridLayouts.css";

.card {
    background: transparent;
    width: 117px;
    height: 200px;
    perspective: 1000px; /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    transition: transform 0.8s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.wrapper-horizontal .card {
    float: left;
    margin-right: -47px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */
.card:hover {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translate(0, 40px);
}

/* Position the front and back side */
.card-face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari */
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */
.card-face-front {
    background: url("...") -234px 0px;
}

/* Style the back side */
.card-face-back {
    background: url("...");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="Stylesheets/FlipCardStyle.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Stylesheets/GridLayouts.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Stylesheets/Buttons.css">

<html>

<div class="wrapper-horizontal">

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-face card-face-front"></div>
        <div class="card-face card-face-back"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-face card-face-front"></div>
        <div class="card-face card-face-back"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-face card-face-front"></div>
        <div class="card-face card-face-back"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-face card-face-front"></div>
        <div class="card-face card-face-back"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="./FlipCard.js"></script>

</div>

<button class="btn">Shuffle</button>

</html>
```

**Theoretically**, when I clicked the card, js script will invoke the .card.flipped, which would rotate the card over. But it doesn't work...  My logic of the code comes from https://codepen.io/mondal10/pen/WNNEvjV, it workds on codepen but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Could anyone help me? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Your html structure doesn't make any sense

Comment: Hi! Please **reduce** the code in the question to a runnable [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: There is no style for `.card.flipped`.

Comment: Is that your actual html - if so it's completely invalid.

Comment: I posted a snippet where your code will work, However make sure that next time you post a question you create a minimal reproducible example as TJ Crowder said, and also to make sure that you write your code using valid HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current included HTML is invalid, and you have a CSS selector that turns the cards around when hovered, I changed `.card:hover` to be `.flipped` because there was no `flipped` class to be toggled by the JavaScript. And I removed the invalid HTML, also replaced the background images that linked to nothing to colors, so it shows the cards in the following snippet.

```js
var cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');

[...cards].forEach((card) => {
  card.addEventListener('click', function() {
    card.classList.toggle('flipped');
  });
});
```

```css
.card {
  background: transparent;
  width: 117px;
  height: 200px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.wrapper-horizontal .card {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


/* changed .card:hover to .flipped because there was no class to be toggled. */

.flipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translate(0, 40px);
}

.card-face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card-face-front {
  background: red;
}

.card-face-back {
  background: blue;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-horizontal">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-face card-face-front"></div>
    <div class="card-face card-face-back"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-face card-face-front"></div>
    <div class="card-face card-face-back"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-face card-face-front"></div>
    <div class="card-face card-face-back"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-face card-face-front"></div>
    <div class="card-face card-face-back"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="./FlipCard.js"></script>
</div>
<button class="btn">Shuffle</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! I wonder how can I run it locally on chrome cuz it seemesto be fine on Snippet but whenever I copy the code and run that on Chrome it fails. I have added css and js references in html files, and my Chrome does support js...

Comment: Here you can find the index.html, style.css and script.js
https://github.com/REFUZIION/flipping-cards

Comment: If this answer has given you the solution make sure to mark it as the answer so other people facing the same issues as you are able to find the answer.

Comment: It works! Huge appreciations

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you copy all the source code from codepen without knowing the code format and structure

```js
var cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');

[...cards].forEach((card) => {
  card.addEventListener('click', function() {
    card.classList.toggle('is-flipped');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.scene {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  /*   border: 1px solid #CCC; */
  margin: 40px 0;
  perspective: 600px;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: center right;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.card.is-flipped {
  transform: translateX(-100%) rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card__face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 260px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card__face--front {
  background: crimson;
}

.card__face--back {
  background: slateblue;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <meta property="og:title" content="">
  <meta property="og:type" content="">
  <meta property="og:url" content="">
  <meta property="og:image" content="">

  <link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.png">
  <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

  <meta name="theme-color" content="#fafafa">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
  <div class="scene scene--card">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__face card__face--front">front</div>
      <div class="card__face card__face--back">back</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="scene scene--card">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__face card__face--front">front</div>
      <div class="card__face card__face--back">back</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>Click card to flip.</p>

  <script src="js/main.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```